# Can I detect if an imported ALAsset photo was taken via screenshot?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, alassetslibrary

I have an `imagePickerController` that is used for importing photos from library into my app.

When in `ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock`, I'm trying to find out if the ALAsset I've got in the block is a photo taken as a screen-shot or is it a "genuine" photo, taken by the camera.

I've tried to go through the ALAsset's metadata dictionaries but couldn't find any flag / indication that might fit.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: for that you need to check the size of the photo is 460*320 then that photo capture from the screen shot i think this is a only way to detect the screen shot?

Comment: @neonsamuel - Thanks, but I don't think we should rely on the sizes (Especially when iphone 5's new ratio is here...)

Comment: So you need to include one more condition for that :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was researching and experimenting .. and the closest solution I've found is based on the fact that iPhone screenshots don't yield EXIF records (while all other generated photos do generate them).

Therefore, once a photo is selected in the picker, I'm checking if the photo's metadata consists an EXIF record and if it doesn't - I conclude that the photo was screenshot.

I found it's the "as good as it gets" solution for now, although it's not an official one.

Cheers.

Comment: For photos saved from web page may also have no EXIF metadata.

Answer (score 3):

For screenshot, its UTI is always a "public.png" and same size as screen (be sure you have multiply [UIScreen scale] on screen bounds width and height), just need to check these 2 metadata, you can easily identify screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Add **MetaData** to **UIImage** while **saving to Photo Library**. Same metadata of UIImage can be used to know if its screenshot or not.

Refer [Save_Photo_to_Album_with_Metadata](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/recipes/Media/Video_and_Photos/Save_Photo_to_Album_with_Metadata)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm talking about photos that were taken by another app (and not mine..) - where I can't control the metadata that's written upon save..