# When enumerating ALAssetsLibrary, can I distinguish screen-short-cut images and camera-taken images?

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary

Now I only want to get the screen-short-cut images.

Is there any way to distinguish screen-short-cut images and camera-taken images when enumerating the ALAssetsLibrary?

Thans very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953669/can-i-detect-if-an-imported-alasset-photo-was-taken-via-screenshot) out. This might help you. There is no straight forward way to find it. You will have to use some hack.