# How to retrieve PHAsset from UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, photos

I'm trying to retrieve a PHAsset however PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs:options:) is deprecated from iOS 8 so how can I properly retrieve a PHAsset?

Answer (score 20):

I had the same the issue, first check permissions and request access:

```
let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()

if status == .notDetermined  {
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({status in

    })
}
```

Just hook that up to whatever triggers your UIImagePickerController. The delegate call should now include the PHAsset in the userInfo.

```
guard let asset = info[UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset] as? PHAsset
```

Comment: This is available to iOS 11.0 and above. Any solution for lower versions of iOS?

Comment: I get `nil` for this in the simulator.

Comment: The info key enums have changed to be more Swift-like. Replace `UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset` with `UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.phAsset`, or just `.phAsset`.

Comment: I had this problem on iPhone 6s but not on iPhone XSMax, after this suggestion works on 6S also, btw both iPhone's are on latest iOS 13.5 firmware

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
               let asset = info[UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset]

        } else {
               if let assetURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL {
               let result = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [assetURL], options: nil)
               let asset = result.firstObject
               }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The PHAsset will not appear in the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: info` result unless the user has authorized, which did not happen for me just by presenting the picker.  I added this in the Coordinator init():

```
            let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()

            if status == .notDetermined  {
                PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({status in

                })
            }
```

Comment: This helped! It's really not obvious you need to ask for authorization, because the picker shows up, and returns images even without it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want.

Are you trying to target iOS 8?

This is how I fetch photos and it works in **iOS (8.0 and later), macOS (10.11 and later), tvOS (10.0 and later).**
Code is commented where it may be confusing

1. The first functions sets the options to fetch the photos
2. The second function will actually fetch them

   ```
    //import the Photos framework
    import Photos
    //in these arrays I store my images and assets
    var images = [UIImage]()
    var assets = [PHAsset]()

    fileprivate func setPhotoOptions() -> PHFetchOptions{
           let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
           fetchOptions.fetchLimit = 15
           let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)
           fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
           return fetchOptions
       }




   fileprivate func fetchPhotos() {
   let allPhotos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: setPhotoOptions())

   DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

       allPhotos.enumerateObjects({ (asset, count, stop) in
           let imageManager = PHImageManager.default()
           let targetSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
           let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
           options.isSynchronous = true
           imageManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: options, resultHandler: { (image, info) in

               if let image = image {
                   self.images.append(image)
                   self.assets.append(asset)


               }

               if count == allPhotos.count - 1 {
                   DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       //basically, here you can do what you want
                       //(after you finish retrieving your assets)
                       //I am reloading my collection view
                       self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                   }
               }

           })


       })

   }
   ```

   }

Edit based on OP's clarification

You need to set the delegate **UIImagePickerControllerDelegate**

then implement the following function

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
```

within said method, get the image like this:

```
var image : UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as! UIImage
```

Comment: I want to retrieve the PHAsset from an image that I have gotten from UIImagePickerController

Comment: I can't believe the only way to do this is fetch the whole photo library and then enumerate each photo!