# How determine if an image is a Screenshot in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, image, dart, screenshot, exif

I'm trying to determine if an image is a screenshot.

Here's all I get with the [exif](https://pub.dev/packages/exif) lib, I can't see info about the camera type. I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69214323/15481204) that a key "UserComment" seems to be what I'm looking for but I don't find it.

```
flutter: Image PhotometricInterpretation Short: 2
flutter: Image Make ASCII: NIKON CORPORATION
flutter: Image Model ASCII: NIKON D90
flutter: Image Orientation Short: Horizontal (normal)
flutter: Image XResolution Ratio: 72
flutter: Image YResolution Ratio: 72
flutter: Image ResolutionUnit Short: Pixels/Inch
flutter: Image Software ASCII: QuickTime 7.7.1
flutter: Image DateTime ASCII: 2011:05:03 20:30:44
flutter: Image YCbCrPositioning Short: Centered
flutter: Image ExifOffset Long: 238
flutter: GPS GPSLatitudeRef ASCII: N
flutter: GPS GPSLatitude Ratio: [38, 2, 74/5]
flutter: GPS GPSLongitudeRef ASCII: W
flutter: GPS GPSLongitude Ratio: [122, 48, 286/25]
flutter: Image GPSInfo Long: 564
flutter: Thumbnail Compression Short: JPEG (old-style)
flutter: Thumbnail XResolution Ratio: 72
flutter: Thumbnail YResolution Ratio: 72
flutter: Thumbnail ResolutionUnit Short: Pixels/Inch
flutter: Thumbnail JPEGInterchangeFormat Long: 760
flutter: Thumbnail JPEGInterchangeFormatLength Long: 10181
flutter: EXIF ExposureTime Ratio: 1/1600
flutter: EXIF FNumber Ratio: 4
flutter: EXIF ExposureProgram Short: Aperture Priority
flutter: EXIF ISOSpeedRatings Short: 200
flutter: EXIF ExifVersion Undefined: 0220
flutter: EXIF DateTimeOriginal ASCII: 2011:03:12 16:17:25
flutter: EXIF DateTimeDigitized ASCII: 2011:03:12 16:17:25
flutter: EXIF ComponentsConfiguration Undefined: YCbCr
flutter: EXIF ExposureBiasValue Signed Ratio: 0
flutter: EXIF MaxApertureValue Ratio: 4
flutter: EXIF MeteringMode Short: Pattern
flutter: EXIF LightSource Short: Cool white fluorescent (W 3900 - 4500K)
flutter: EXIF Flash Short: Flash did not fire
flutter: EXIF FocalLength Ratio: 26
flutter: EXIF FlashPixVersion Undefined: 0100
flutter: EXIF ColorSpace Short: sRGB
flutter: EXIF ExifImageWidth Long: 4288
flutter: EXIF ExifImageLength Long: 2848
flutter: EXIF SensingMethod Short: One-chip color area
flutter: EXIF SceneCaptureType Short: Standard
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if an uploaded image is a screenshot iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272375/check-if-an-uploaded-image-is-a-screenshot-ios)

Comment: ``"Screenshots don't have any EXIF data"``. Answer from the link you added https://stackoverflow.com/a/37185143/5882307